# I need to format a textbox to accept number as ###,###,###

Tags: c#, .net

I have a textbox in a C# form where I want users to just enter number in following format:

```
###,###,###
```

This means a user can enter any number upto 3 digit and then a comma and another number and so on. All 3 numbers are not necessarily required but there should atleast be 1 number.

To clarify I have given examples below

```
333,222,111   > Correct
3,1,2         > Correct
3             > Correct
0             > Incorrect
3,            > Incorrect
3,3           > Correct
33,22         > Correct
3,22          > Correct
3,33,         > Incorrect
3,33,,        > Incorrect
33,33,33,33   > Incorrect
33            > Correct
```

This will be checked when a person clicks a button after entering the string in textbox. If incorrect incorrect, the messagebox should just say "Incorrect number format".

Comment: I can't believe I'm saying this, but this sounds like a *perfect* case for a regex. Now I just have to dust off the old reg-ex documentation...

Comment: Why `0` is not correct? It satisfies the rules you stated.

Comment: I require a solution other than Regex. Is String.Format possible ?? Number should be 1-999 (not 0)

Comment: String.Format just formats a string, it won't check an existing string pattern. This is *exactly* what a regex is for. You could do your own loop check I suppose, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a regex check as Brandley mentioned.

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}|[1-9]\d{0,2},\d{1,3}|[1-9]\d{0,2})$
```

Edited: if regex is not a solution then do a split

```
string[] sArray = yourString.Split(',');
if(sArray.Length > 3)
 return false;

foreach(string element in sArray)
{
    if (//int try parse)
    {
        if (//parsed int >1000 or <0)
          return false;
    }
    else 
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BradleyDotNET 123,12 is valid based on his example

Comment: I see that. I gave up on figuring it out, and posted my alternative.

Comment: I require a solution other than Regex. Is String.Format possible ?? Number should be 1-999 (not 0)

Comment: @Newbiecoder string.Format is used to format string, not for checking

Comment: @Newbiecoder see if you can go with the Split method

Answer (score 2):

You could parse an input string without regex as follows:

```
public static bool IsValid(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return false;

    string[] tokens = input.Split(',');
    if (tokens.Length > 3)
        return false;

    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            return false;
        int val;
        if (!int.TryParse(token, out val))
            return false;
        if (val <= 0 || val > 999)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for a regex, namely this would match:

> ^((\d{3},)*\d?\d?\d)$

Used like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^((\d{3},)*\d?\d?\d)$");
return regex.Matches(strInput);
```

000,000,000 and 0 are valid numbers with this regex (and are actual numbers too!)

Comment: 0 is not valid and this regex matches it :D

Comment: @Steve Thats a stupid requirement :D I may just have to defer to your answer; this is about as far as me and regexs go. I generally have two problems when I try to use them to solve one :)

Comment: haha yea..i thought about making it into one expression too, and then I was like....dam the 0 case